# How does agda's inspect function work?

Tags: proof, agda

I've seen an example of the inspect function in my last question [Using the value of a computed function for a proof in agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478269/using-the-value-of-a-computed-function-for-a-proof-in-agda#18494370) , but I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around that.

Here's a simple example:

Given the function `crazy`,

```
crazy : ℕ -> ℕ
crazy 0 = 10
crazy 1 = 0
crazy 2 = 0
crazy 3 = 1
crazy 4 = 0
crazy xxx = xxx
```

I want to create a `safe` function such that `safe : {nn : ℕ} -> (id nn) ≢ 0 -> Fin (id nn)`.  In other words it will return one number mod crazy, if you give it a proof crazy is 0.  (I know that the example is a little contrived and I would probably be better off using the `suc` in the function signature)

My first solution is

```
safebad : {nn : ℕ} -> (crazy nn) ≢ 0 -> Fin (crazy nn)
safebad {1} hh with hh refl
... | ()
safebad {2} hh with hh refl
... | ()
safebad {4} hh with hh refl
... | ()
safebad {0} hh = # 0
safebad {3} hh = # 0
safebad {suc (suc (suc (suc (suc _))))} _ = # 0
```

But this is long and messy.  So I tried to emulate the example in [Using the value of a computed function for a proof in agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478269/using-the-value-of-a-computed-function-for-a-proof-in-agda#18494370) but could only get so far

```
safegood : (nn : ℕ) -> (crazy nn) ≢ 0 -> Fin (crazy nn)
safegood nn nez with crazy nn | inspect crazy nn
... | 0 | [ proof ] = ⊥-elim ???
... | _ | _ = # 0
```

inspect uses Hidden to hide a record of the function application in the type signature, I think.  This can then be retrieved with reveal.

This is what I think I understand:

`Reveal_is_` seems to hold  the value of the hidden `f`, and `x`; and the result of `x` applied to `f`.  `[_]` will result in the proof of that equality.

`⊥-elim` takes a proof of contradiction and returns a contradiction.

What do I put into `???` for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it needlessly complicated. `inspect` is only useful when you need to use the proof that the value before pattern matching is equal to the value after pattern matching. Notice that you have `nez` in the scope which makes this trivial.

What we really want to do is to reduce the assumption `crazy nn ≢ 0` to `0 ≢ 0` which we can easily use to construct a contradiction. How do we get `crazy nn` to reduce to `0`? You have already tried the first option - go through all possible `crazy` arguments and fish for those that indeed reduce `crazy nn` to `0`. The other option is to simply abstract over the value of `crazy nn`.

First, the goal type before we use `with` is `Fin (crazy nn)` and the type of `nez` is `crazy nn ≢ 0`. Now, we abstract over `crazy nn`:

```
safegood nn nez with crazy nn
... | w = ?
```

Notice our goal is now `Fin w` and `nez`'s type is `w ≢ 0`, much easier to work with! And finally, we pattern match on `w`:

```
safegood nn nez with crazy nn
... | zero  = ?
... | suc w = ?
```

The first goal is now `Fin 0` and we have a `0 ≢ 0` as one of our assumptions. This is obviously a nonsense, combining `nez` with `refl` gives us a contradiction that can be used by `⊥-elim`:

```
safegood nn nez with crazy nn
... | zero  = ⊥-elim (nez refl)
... | suc w = ?
```

No `inspect` in sight! In fact, using `inspect` here is like making a round trip: you reduce `crazy nn` to `0` in the types, get a proof that `crazy nn ≡ 0` and now you need to "unreduce" `0` back to `crazy nn` so that you can use `nez proof`.

---

For the sake of completeness: you can avoid pattern matching on `crazy nn` to keep the type of the proof `nez` intact by using the deprecated `inspect`:

```
open Deprecated-inspect
  renaming (inspect to inspect′)

safegood₂ : (nn : ℕ) → crazy nn ≢ 0 → Fin (crazy nn)
safegood₂ nn nez with inspect′ (crazy nn)
... | zero  with-≡ eq = ⊥-elim (nez eq)
... | suc _ with-≡ eq = ?
```

Since we abstract over `inspect′ (crazy nn)`, no `crazy nn` subexpressions will get substituted and `nez` will keep its original type.

---

Talking about crazy roundtrips: you could use `proof` to reconstruct `nez`'s original type; again, this is more of a "might be useful to know" than "use this here":

```
safegood : (nn : ℕ) → crazy nn ≢ 0 → Fin (crazy nn)
safegood nn nez with crazy nn | inspect crazy nn
... | 0 | [ proof ] = ⊥-elim (subst (λ x → x ≢ 0) (sym proof) nez proof)
... | _ | _         = ?
```